# higher order structure by higher order derivatives

Tags: examples

Anyone recall a structure determined by a 3rd order partial derivative?
not the general nth order of recent Baranovsky

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does "structure determined by a 3rd order partial" mean?

Comment: Have you considered having a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14841 ?
Or else, to repeat the question of Hans: what is your question?

Comment: Just in case (but I am to far from this topic): a foliated $3$-web in the plane is linearizable if and only if its curvature is $\equiv0$. Isn't true that this curvature involves the third derivatives of the vector field defining the foliations ? 

Answer (score 6):

The [Schwarzian derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzian_derivative) is third-order and plays an important role in the geometry of the projective line.

Answer (score 4):

The associativity condition for the symmetric 3-tensor in a [Frobenius manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_manifold) is a third-order PDE on the potential: the so-called WDVV equation.

Comment: Jos\'e,
   That is the one I was after. Apologies for the vagueness of my question,thinking it did have something to do with Frobenius manifolds, but having not found the answer in Dubrovin,
I thought that too might be a faulty memory.

Comment: Jim, glad to have been of help!  
